# R idiom for switch/case

Tags: r, switch-statement

I've got some R code that looks basically like this:

```
compute.quantiles <- function(mu, type) {

  ## 'mu' and 'type' are vectors of the same length

  var <- ifelse(type=='a', 6.3523 * mu^2,
         ifelse(type=='b', 234.23 * mu,
         ifelse(type=='c', {s <- 9.8 * ((mu-0.3)/3)^(6/7)+0.19; mu + mu^2/s},
         ifelse(type=='d', 56.345 * mu^1.5,
         ifelse(type=='e', 0.238986 * mu^2,
         ifelse(type=='f', mu + 1.1868823 * mu^2,
         NA ))))))

  # ...then do something with var...
}
```

Some sample input & output:

```
print(compute.quantiles(2:4, c('c','d','e')))
[1]   2.643840 292.777208   3.823776
```

That works correctly, but it's kind of ugly with the deep nesting, so I'm wondering if there's a different idiom that works better.  Anyone have a suggestion?  If `switch()` accepted a vector as its first argument, that would work nicely, but it just takes a scalar.

Comment: could you provide a small reproducible data set to try this out?

Comment: All those answers are clever, but they don't send idiomatic. Therefore, the interesting question about the idiomatic way to do this in R keeps open.

Comment: I prefer over switch to use `dplyr::case_when` or `data.table::fcase` which is not too different from chained ifelse-statements. `switch` is limited to strings and numerics. In this case matching strings, something switch like is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I came up with something I like better:

```
## Vector-switch
vswitch <- function(EXPR, ...) {
    vars <- cbind(...)
    vars[cbind(seq_along(EXPR), match(EXPR, names(list(...))))]
}

compute.quantiles <- function(mu, type) {
  stopifnot(length(mu) == length(type))

  vswitch( type,
    a = 6.3523 * mu^2,
    b = 234.23 * mu,
    c = mu + mu^2/(9.8 * ((mu-0.3)/3)^(6/7)+0.19),
    d = 56.345 * mu^1.5,
    e = 0.238986 * mu^2,
    f = mu + 1.1868823 * mu^2)
}
```

With the matrix-indexing code in just 2 lines, I think it's ok for my too-clever-code threshold. =)

Comment: +1 I was contemplating your other answer and thought: why not make a `vswitch` function - and now you already did! Same name and everything :)

Comment: =) [52 more chars added to reach posting threshold...]

Comment: +1 It's very strange but switch does not work in a parameterized rmarkdown report (the parameter is a greek letter - I don't know if that is the problem). However vswitch worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(data.table)
# Case selection table:
dtswitch <- data.table(type=letters[1:6],
                      result=c("6.3523 * mu^2",
                               "234.23 * mu",
                               "{s <- 9.8 * ((mu-0.3)/3)^(6/7)+0.19; mu + mu^2/s}",
                               "56.345 * mu^1.5",
                               "0.238986 * mu^2",
                               "mu + 1.1868823 * mu^2"),
                      key="type")

# Data to which you want the cases applied:
compute <- data.table(type=letters[3:5],mu=2:4,key="type")

# Join the data table with the case selection table, and evaluate the results:
dtswitch[compute,list(mu,result=eval(parse(text=result)))]
#>   type mu     result
#>1:    c  2   2.643840
#>2:    d  3 292.777208
#>3:    e  4   3.823776
```

Rather than creating the dtswitch table in R code, you could store it in an external spreadsheet or database and then load it into R.  Might be handy if you have a lot of different cases or they are changing often and you want to control them from a central location.

Answer (score 3):

Ken Williams' implementation of `vswitch` does not work well for some type of inputs. I think this one is more flexible:

```
vswitch <- function(expr, ...) {
  lookup <- list(...)
  vec <- as.character(expr)
  vec[is.na(vec)] <- "NA"
  unname(do.call(c, lookup[vec]))
}
```

To use it with numeric lookup values, you need to quote or backquote them:

```
num_vec <- c(1, 3, 2, 2, 1)
vswitch(num_vec, `1` = 10, `2` = 25, `3` = 50)
## [1] 10 50 25 25 10
```

With character lookups:

```
char_vec <- letters[num_vec]
vswitch(char_vec, a = "Albert", b = "Bertrand", c = "Charles")
## [1] "Albert"   "Charles"  "Bertrand" "Bertrand" "Albert"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is workable:

```
compute.quantiles <- function(mu, type) {
  stopifnot(length(mu) == length(type))

  vars <- cbind(
    a = 6.3523 * mu^2,
    b = 234.23 * mu,
    c = mu + mu^2/(9.8 * ((mu-0.3)/3)^(6/7)+0.19),
    d = 56.345 * mu^1.5,
    e = 0.238986 * mu^2,
    f = mu + 1.1868823 * mu^2)

  vars[cbind(seq_along(mu), match(type, colnames(vars)))]
}
```

Not sure if that's going to look too "advanced" for the future reader (including myself) though.

Comment: And regarding "too advanced" - you might consider a comment explaining what's goin' on... Don't fear the comments :)

Comment: ...and use `seq_along(mu)` instead of `1:length(mu)` so that you handle zero-length vectors...

Comment: And regarding the comments - I don't fear comments, but whenever I put in a comment that basically says "here's why this code is so wonky...", my gut wrenches & I end up changing the code until the comment isn't needed anymore. =)  Or at least, it seems like that to me, since I've spent so much time on it that it's "obvious" in my head. =)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist adding another answer with a completely different approach.  Here it is.

```
## Sort of a cross between tapply() and ave()
tswitch <- function(x, INDEX, ...) {
  l <- substitute(list(...))
  s <- split(x, INDEX)
  pf <- parent.frame()
  split(x, INDEX) <- lapply(names(s), function(n) 
    eval(l[[n]], list(x=s[[n]]), pf)
  )
  x
}

compute.quantiles <- function(mu, type) {
  stopifnot(length(mu) == length(type))

  tswitch(mu, type,
    a = 6.3523 * x^2,
    b = 234.23 * x,
    c = x + x^2/(9.8 * ((x-0.3)/3)^(6/7)+0.19),
    d = 56.345 * x^1.5,
    e = 0.238986 * x^2,
    f = x + 1.1868823 * x^2)
}
```

And the sample input & output:

```
> compute.quantiles(2:4, c('c','d','e'))
[1]   2.643840 292.777208   3.823776
```

The advantage to this implementation is that it only computes the `length(mu)` specific values that need to be computed.  By contrast, the `vswitch` method above computes `length(mu) * M` values, where `M` is the number of "cases" in the switch.  So if the computations are costly, or if the data is big, this version could be a win.